# Solution of a polynomial in interval $(0,1)$

Tags: polynomials, roots

Let $\displaystyle a_0 + \frac{a_1}{2} + \frac{a_2}{3} + ... + \frac{a_n}{n+1} = 0$, where $a_i$'s are some real constants.

How can we prove that the equation $a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + ... +a_nx^n = 0$ has at least one solution in the interval $(0,1)$?

Comment: (I know that the question I linked to was asked later, but it has more views and at least one question already closed as duplicate.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that $a_0 + a_1x + a_2 x^2 + \cdots + a_nx^n$ is continuous and 
$$\int_0^1 (a_0 + a_1x + a_2 x^2 + \cdots + a_nx^n) dx = 0$$

Comment: @user17762. It is true but does that imply that it has the root in $(0,1)$? Pardon me, I am weak at this.

Comment: @gaathiyo this implies that the polynomial cannot be always positive or always negative in $(0, 1)$, so by intermediate value theorem there is a root in $(0, 1)$.

Comment: @IvanLoh: How about showing there exists a root in $(0,1)$ without the means of calculus?

Comment: @Inceptio: why? this is a popular "challenging" calculus question that is at least a decade or two old.

Comment: @oldrinb: But this question seems crack-able with pre-calculus methods. And if I'm not wrong use of calculus isn't encouraged in solving Olympiad problems.

Comment: @Inceptio: I did not come across it as an Olympiad problem, but it very well may be. I'd argue it's intended to be solved with calculus, hence the terms in our given being $\frac{a_k}{k+1}$.

Comment: @oldrinb: The question is 'Why not?', many polynomial Olympiad questions are of this type.:)